# Socket.io using by React and nodeJs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, websocket, socket.io

If you have an error: when you are using Socket.io in **client side** like this:

**code:**

```
import io from "socket.io-client";
const socket = io(<your_end_point>);
```

**Error:**

```
GET http://localhost:<your_end_point>/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NZHEHaCnet::ERR_FAILED
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

```
const socket = io(<your_end_point>, {
      transports: ["websocket", "polling", "flashsocket"],
    });
```